How do you disable notifications for system apps on Android 14?
I have a device running on Android 14. There is the "Codec status" app, which is a system app. I want to disable its notifications, but the "Show notifications" toggle is greyed out.

I've searched around a bit, but the only answers I could find were for older versions of Android that don't really work anymore or require root access, which I would like to avoid, given that I like having a warranty.
How do you disable notifications for system apps on Android 14?

I'd assume you have seen "Show notifications" is greyed out for some apps. What's causing it and how do I change it? which was about older Android and/or needs root.

This question is similar to: "Show notifications" is greyed out for some apps. What's causing it and how do I change it?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
